# Can we use a package without setting the classpath in java

Tags: java

I was reading about class-path and came across this question and couldn't find right answer. so, can anyone explain me with suitable example.

Comment: *Everything* is in a package in Java. You might go at least some way to answer your own question by looking into 'default package'

Comment: Everything is in a package (if you lack a `package` statement, it's in the _default_ package). And classpath is always set; if you don't use the `-classpath` option, you get the CLASSPATH environment variable, and if you don't set that, it'll default to `.`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Yes. Although I'm not sure it *always* defaults to `.`. Certainly it usually does. I've heard of some VMs that refuse to operate with a null classpath